# Inner Function Identification

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, chain-rule

I have having an issue identifying the inner function of this function:

> $$f(g(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$$

I "need" to take the derivative of it; hence I have to identify the inner function.  My current thinking is that the inner function is $\sqrt{x+1}$, and outer would be $\frac{1}{x}$.

### Outer

> $$\frac{1}{x}$$

### Inner

> $$\sqrt{x+1}$$

Is my answer to the identification of the outside and inner functions correct?

Comment: Are *both* $f$ and $g$ unknown functions?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Yes that is the approach that is expected for the problem.  I am expected to be applying chain rule to this problem so first I would have to identify the inner, and outer functions.

Comment: Then you have *many* possible solutions. For example, $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is another pair $g(x)=\frac1{x+1}$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Would the one I applied be one of them? If so I would then just delete the question.

Comment: Yes, the one you have given in your question above is one of them.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Great your comment answers my question- Is my answer to the identification of the outside and inner functions correct?- so if you could please write it down, so like that I could close the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47713/discussion-between-enlightenedfunky-and-olivier-oloa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two possible solutions for the inner and outer functions, however, if you are to apply the chain rule, I would suggest just using $(x+1)^\frac{-1}{2}$ for your chain rule